# Could not set field value value by reflection when trying to merge an object to database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a class CompanyUser.java which acts as an inner table for a many to many relation on Company and User. Now I would like to update a value (privilege level) but when doing so I get this error back. I checked all getters and setters. My CompanyUser.java class looks like the following.

```
@Entity
public class CompanyUser
{

   @EmbeddedId
   private CompanyUserId id;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @MapsId("companyId")
   private Company company;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @MapsId("userId")
   private User user;

   @Column(name = "privilege_level")
   private Integer privilegeLevel = CompanyPrivilegeLevel.DEFAULT.getValue();

   public CompanyUser() {}

   public CompanyUser(Company company, User user, Integer priveligeLevel)
   {
      this.company = company;
      this.user = user;
      this.privilegeLevel = priveligeLevel;
      this.id = new CompanyUserId(user.getId(), company.getId());
   }
 ... Getters and Setters ...
}
```

The embedded CompanyUserId.java:

```
@Embeddable
public class CompanyUserId implements Serializable
{

  @Column(name = "user_id")
  private int userId;
  @Column(name = "company_id")
  private int companyId;

  public CompanyUserId() {}

  public CompanyUserId(int userId, int companyId)
  {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.companyId = companyId;
  }
  ... Getters and setters & equals and hashCode method ...
}
```

A nullPointer exception is thrown so I tried changing

```
@EmbeddedId private CompanyUserId id;
```

to

```
@EmbeddedId private CompanyUserId id = new CompanyUserId();
```

But when I do this I get this "Hibernate Error: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session" error.

Thanks in advance.

Exception thrown:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:780) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:368) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:314) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at com.ewa.urbananalytics.ewabackend.repository.JpaCompanyUserRepository.save(JpaCompanyUserRepository.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
```

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @locus2k, I managed to get it working! There was something wrong with the way I was retrieving the object. I don't think it is the most efficient way but for now, it works.

```
@PostMapping("/company/user/save")
@Transactional
public void saveCompanyUser(@RequestBody CompanyUser cu)
{
    CompanyUserId companyUserId = new CompanyUserId(cu.getUser().getId(), cu.getCompany().getId());
    CompanyUser foundCU = companyUserRepository.findById(companyUserId);
    foundCU.setPriveligeLevel(cu.getPrivilegeLevel());
    companyUserRepository.save(foundCU);
}
```

Comment: Glad it worked out

Comment: can you send us the code of merging please... i have a more better solution but i need to know the way that you made, and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not retrieving your CompanyUser correctly for updates.

What you have to do is set the values of the `CompanUserId` you want to update first then query off that object, update the results then persist it.

If you're using SpringRepository you can do something like:

```
CompanyUserId id = new CompanyUserId(1, 1);

CompanyUser user = repo.findById(id);
user.setPrivilegeLevel(1);
repo.save(user);
```

just make sure you do your necessary error handling.

If you're using hibernate for queries your query would look like:

```
String query = "SELECT cu FROM CompanyUser cu WHERE cu.id = :id";

CompanyUserId id = new CompanyUserId(1, 1);
TypedQuery<CompanyUser> q = entityManager.createQuery(query, CompanyUser.class);
q.setParameter("id", id);

CustomerUser user = q.getSingleResult();
user.setPrivilegeLevel(1);
entityManager.persist(user);
```

Make sure to remove `@EmbeddedId private CompanyUserId id = new CompanyUserId();` and set it back to just `@EmbeddedId private CompanyUserId id;`